# Options for adding a timer on heated towel rail socket in UK toilet

Tags: bathroom, heating, timer, socket

I live in the UK - my downstairs toilet consists of just a small sink and a toilet.

Next to the sink is a heated towel rail which is wired straight into the socket, and is controlled by a switch.

I would like to add a timer to control when it comes on and off as it is not connected to the central heating.

I have seen socket adaptors with timers on them (see picture), but this would mean installing a standard plug socket and rewiring the towel rail to have a plug.

[image]

As far as I can tell this is allowed under UK building regs as it is not within 3 metres of a shower or bath, but I am still worried about the proximity to the sink.

Would this be a viable solution or are my concerns founded?

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is attracting VtC as "shopping advice" (and "needs more focus" which I really don't get). I _think_ that if you edit to focus on the "plug near the sink" aspect, you'll be OK, as any sort of power timer control should otherwise do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've edited the question to focus more on the plug near the sink aspect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allowed, but there are lots of timeswitched fused connection units available if you'd prefer not to have a plug/socket.

Selection here:

https://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Main_Index/Timers_Index/Immersion_Heater_Timers_1/index.html

Edit to add: all sockets **must** now be RCD protected. If the existing circuit is not RCD protected you **must not** change the fused connection unit to a socket.

Comment: That seems like the ideal solution, I didn't know these existed. Thanks a lot Owain

Comment: Couldn't you put a RCD at the FCU location if the circuit wasn't RCD protected already?

Comment: Unfortunately not in *strict* compliance with current standards. BS7671 requires equipment to satisfy the relevant standards. The British Standard for socket and FCU RCDs BS7288:2016 stipulates that SRCDs provide *supplementary* protection, but that *additional* protection must be provided upstream. BS7288 has been omitted from BS7671 as a type of RCD suitable for providing primary protection for fixed wiring. This is a change from previous editions of BS7671 and also BS7288:1990.

Comment: This omission may be corrected in future editions of the standards. In many cases of course an electrician will install a BS7288 device and record it as a deviation from BS7671 and some certification bodies are recommending BS7288 devices where there is no other easy means of providing RCD protection.